What's the factory name for the ARGB connector
Similar to the Fan Header, that it is known as KF2510 or KK254
What's the name for this argb connector?


The LED lighting industry adopted a standard shroudless PCB header with round pins and 2.54 mm pitch. It's really meant to be soldered to a PCB, not to wires. Eventually, some started molding the PCB header in plastic, turning it into a plug. But it's not any actual plug, one you can buy. It's just wires soldered to a female socket strip and stuck in an injection molding tool. In your particular example, they molded one pin shut to key it.

{Source: MillMax 801-47-004-10-002000 on Digikey]

Is there an article or document where we can further investigate this new standard?

"this new standard" it is not a standard. It's just something that some Chinese company started doing, and others copied it.
